# Most efficient way to find longest incrementing subsequence in a list of lists

Tags: python, algorithm, signal-processing

I am doing some signal analysis, a part of which is to find the longest subsequence

I have dictionary like the following:

```
sequenceDict = {
    0: [168, 360, 470],
    1: [279, 361, 471, 633, 729, 817],
    2: [32, 168, 170, 350, 634, 730, 818],
    3: [33, 155, 171, 363, 635, 731, 765, 819],
    4: [352, 364, 732, 766, 822],
    5: [157, 173, 353, 577, 637, 733, 823, 969],
    6: [158, 174, 578, 638, 706, 734, 824],
    7: [159, 175, 579, 707, 735],
    8: [160, 464, 640, 708, 826],
    9: [173, 709, 757, 827],
    10: [174, 540, 642, 666, 710],
    11: [253, 667, 711],
    12: [254, 304, 668],
    13: [181, 255, 831],
    14: [256, 340, 646, 832],
    16: [184, 416], 
    17: [417], 
    18: [418], 
    19: [875], 
    20: [876], 
    23: [217], 
    24: [168, 218, 880], 
    25: [219, 765, 881], 
    26: [220, 766], 
    27: [221], 
    28: [768], 
    29: [3, 769], 
    30: [344, 476, 706]}
```

These are essentially always sorted indices of another array, I would like to find the longest incrementing sequence ( just like a [longest increasing subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence)), by picking only one number from each key sequentially ( key 2 comes right after key 1 and so on), for example, 
from keys 0 and 1, [360, 361] is one sequence, and [470, 471] is another.
I am calling these incrementing sequence, as these numbers should strictly increase by 1.

I have looked at things like [patience sorting](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence#Python) and so on, but since this problem is slightly different, and also has a tree of sequences, are there any known python implementations, or other efficient ways to do this except generating all possible sequences from this dict and then running patience sort?

Comment: Could you reduce the amount of data in the example. We don't really need so much to understand the problem and what solution you expect. You really need to post what you've tried.

Comment: Each of your arrays in the dict seem to be sorted. Is this a given, or just coincidence?

Comment: @haraldkl: This is a given, edited the question accordingly.

Comment: @PeterWood: Reduced the data in the question. The only idea I have is the brute force method, as I mentioned. The link for the implementation is posted, the only other thing will be the for loops.

Comment: @haraldkl The sequence needs to be in a sequence of keys "picking only one number from each key sequentially  ( key 2 comes right after key 1 and so on) " , if it is unclear, please suggest, and I will update the question.

Comment: Probably I was just not realising it. Maybe it would help to list the requirements in a list of bullets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In contrast to @6502's solution, this one not only keeping the best solution but also keeps track of every incrementing subsequences, if this is more helpful.**

The idea is a similar to the sliding window approach. You start from the first list, update `currentHotItems` and `globalHotItems` dictionaries and then see the second list and update the dictionaries again, etc.

```
# fill missing indexes in the dictionary:
for i in range(min(sequenceDict), max(sequenceDict)):
    if i not in sequenceDict:
        sequenceDict[i] = []

# get only lists, ordered:
sortedItems = map(lambda x:x[1], sorted(sequenceDict.items(), key=lambda x:x[0]))    
globalHotItems = {} # (value, startIndex): length
currentHotItems = {} # value: length

for i in range(len(sortedItems)):
    updatedHotItems = {} # updated value: length
    for item in sortedItems[i]:
        if (item - 1) in currentHotItems:
            updatedHotItems[item] = currentHotItems[item-1] + 1
        else:
            updatedHotItems[item] = 1

    deadSet = set(currentHotItems.keys()) - \
            set(updatedHotItems.keys() + [key - 1 for key in updatedHotItems.keys()])

    for item in deadSet:
        globalHotItems[ (item-currentHotItems[item]+1, i-currentHotItems[item]) ] = currentHotItems[item]

    currentHotItems = updatedHotItems

print sorted(globalHotItems.items(), key=lambda x:x[1])[-1]
```

`globalHotItems` is the dictionary which contains the result. Keys are (value, startIndex) and Value's are the length.

For example, the last 4 items in `globalHotItems`:

```
print sorted(globalHotItems.items(), key=lambda x:x[1])[-4:]
```

is:

```
[((157, 5), 4), ((217, 23), 5), ((706, 6), 6), ((729, 1), 7)]
```

it means the best solution is length 7 and starts in the `index=1` list as 729. And the best second solution is length 6 and start in `index=6` list as 706, etc.

**Complexity:**

I think complexity should be again: `O(input_size × average_number_of_sequences)`

Comment: +1 for added functionality of competing solutions. However, could you recheck your code? When I run this with the whole dataset, the value and length is correct, but the index is not.

Comment: @SahilM, the problem was due to the missing indices in the given dictionary. I didn't know you had missing indices in the beginning... However, I fixed it and updated my answer now, **it should work**.

Comment: I may try to help you if you could provide a concrete example that this solution fails.

Answer (score 4):

I would just implement a "brute-force" solution...

1. keep a list of "current sequences", initially empty
2. for each key check if any of the current sequences can be extended by one step. When increasing a sequence update also a best-so-far solution.
3. for any number that was not used to extend a sequence start a new sequence of length 1

Python provides `set` that may be a reasonable choice... this is a sample implementation:

```
best = None
current_sequences = set()
last_key = None
for key in sorted(sequenceDict.keys()):
    data = set(sequenceDict[key])
    new_sequences = set()
    if last_key == key-1:
        # no gap in key value, may be some sequence got extended
        for val, count in current_sequences:
            if val+1 in data:
                # found a continuation, keep this sequence
                new_sequences.add((val+1, count+1))
                data.remove(val+1)
                if best is None or count+1 > best[0]:
                    # we've got a new champion
                    best = count+1, val+1, key
    # add new sequences starting here
    for v in data:
        new_sequences.add((v, 1))
        if best is None:
            best = 1, v, key
    current_sequences = new_sequences
    last_key = key
```

One tricky part is that if there is a gap in the keys then you cannot extend a sequence, this is what `last_key` is used for.

Complexity should be `O(input_size × average_number_of_sequences)`. Mine is just a gut feeling, but my guess is that you cannot get lower than that. I was tempted by the idea of using `value - key` to associate a constant value with each sequence... however this would not detect "gaps" (i.e. value 100 in key 1 and value 102 in key 3, but **without** 101 in key 2).

With the question input the solution is `(7, 735, 7)` meaning a 7-elements sequence ending with value 735 at key 7.

Comment: Thanks, this is great, and +1 for knowing telepathically that there may be empty keys, which is actually a real scenario. 
However, it would be great, if competing solutions could be seen. Would you be able to alter your answer with this for future readers?

Comment: @SahilM: you can just print `current_sequences` at each main loop iteration (i.e. once per key). It's a set of `(current_value, length)` pairs of integers...